# How to use this iterator properly?

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, containers

I'm trying to use a container to store the iterator of string `s`, but I got segment fault when I run it. As you will see in the following, the error seems to come with `char temp = **itbegin;`, it might means I can't assign any value via the previous iterator.

Why is it? Did I misuse the iterator?How to use the iterator properly?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
string reverseVowels(string s);

int main()
{
    string s ="hello";
    cout << reverseVowels(s);
}
string reverseVowels(string s) {
    string::iterator iter = s.begin();
    string::iterator iterend = s.end();
    vector<string::iterator> iteratorbox;
    for(;iter != iterend ; ++iter){
        if((*iter) == 'a' &&
           (*iter) == 'e' &&
           (*iter) == 'i' &&
           (*iter) == 'o' &&
           (*iter) == 'u'){
               iteratorbox.push_back(iter);
           }

    }
    auto itbegin = iteratorbox.begin();
    auto itend =   iteratorbox.end() ;
    --itend;
    //for(;itbegin < itend ; ++itbegin, --itend)
    {
        char temp = **itbegin;
    //    *(*itbegin) = *(*itend); 
    //    *(*itend) = temp;
    }
    return s;
}
```

Comment: To fix that write `char temp = (*itbegin)[0];`

Comment: You should add `#include <string>` to make the code portable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem comes from the condition upon which you insert iterators in your `iteratorbox` vector.

You used the `&&` operator, implying that every letter of the string has to be equal to all vowels **at the same time**. This means no iterator will be inserted, and you are then trying to dereference the `begin()` iterator of the vector, which happens to be its past-the-end iterator. This causes undefined behavior, which in your case manifests itself as a crash.

You probably meant to use

```
((*iter) == 'a' ||
(*iter) == 'e' ||
(*iter) == 'i' ||
(*iter) == 'o' ||
(*iter) == 'u')
```

as a condition.

Comment: @TauBai, please [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23138/how-to-accept-the-answer-on-stack-overflow) the answer, if it is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The answer by @rems4e is perfectly fine, but I find such code easier to read and less error-prone if you put the vowels into an array

```
char const vowels[] = { 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u' };
```

so that you can encapsulate the matching logic inside your `reverseVowels` into the Standard algorithm `any_of`

```
if (std::is_any_of(std::begin(vowels), std::end(vowels), [](auto const& v) {
   return *iter == v;
}) {
    iteratorbox.push_back(iter);
}
```

This avoids much of the repetitive testing (which can get out-of-sync quickly should you ever use a different alphabet (German e.g.))